# Will SO ever archive or delete old question in future

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen that there are many very good answer to questions in SO.
I have links to them saved in my Notes.

I had similar thing done 6-7 years back to one more forum but when I visit those links they are archived or deleted and don't have proper formatting. Some are deleted.

I was thinking if I could have saved the content of them.

So I want to know that some 6-7 years in future, does SO will always have the all questions right from its start so if the volume of questions exceeds which they can't handle then those will be archived or so.

So that I keep saving the content of those good answers.

Comment: The only way something is gonna get deleted if it gets re-categorized as off-topic or unsuitable for the site.

Answer (score 4):

We can not see into the future. But one of the reasons of SO existence is keeping good answers to good questions for other people. So you can assume they are as safe as anything can be on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

> Will Stack Overflow ever delete old question in future?

From [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)

If the post is detected as *extremely off topic* or *very low quality* it may be removed by community or moderators.
Also, OP can also [delete own question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/187824)

But if you have [10K+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) you can see deleted posts too.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, it does sometimes happen that questions are deleted. If a question is likely to be deleted it'll usually meet its fate pretty quickly, but some older questions are deleted as [the values of the site have changed over time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104979/158468), especially if their continued presence on the site seems likely to encourage similar questions that no longer fit the site's goals.

For good questions (and answers), something that's more likely than deletion is that the post may change over time. If other users edit a question or answer to keep it up to date, improve the format, make it more clear, etc., you may no longer recognize it as the thing you're looking for. You can always look back through the edit history, but that's not particularly helpful when you're searching on the basis of a term or phrase that you remember being in the question. While that may be less than helpful, the positive side of it is that edits make questions and answers better for everyone.

If you've searched and can't find the information you're looking for, no matter what the reason, you can always pose a new question and get new answers.